# Xcode error "Multiple commands produce " trying to archive Xcode project

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcodebuild

I've found many answers to questions related to this but all answers point to masking the problem instead of fixing the error. My project doesn't use Pods nor do I want to use the "legacy build system". Whats strange is that I removed all `tvOS` references and libs, but it's still throwing this error after building.

I've tried the suggestions from the [support docs](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/10.0/#/dev14a2fd0c0) with no luck.

The one target for the app also doesn't have duplicate libraries.

[image]

#### My system:

```sh
react-native: 0.57.2
Xcode: 10.1
```

#### Logs:

```sh
error: Multiple commands produce 
1) Target 'third-party' has a command with output '<path>/libthird-party.a'
2) Target 'third-party-tvOS' has a command with output '<path>/libthird-party.a'

error: Multiple commands produce 
1) Target 'double-conversion-tvOS' has a command with output '<path>/libdouble-conversion.a'
2) Target 'double-conversion' has a command with output '<path>/libdouble-conversion.a'
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am in the exact same situation as you.

Comment: @mXX nope. For the time being im still using the legacy build system.

Comment: Too bad! Will keep you updated when I got it to work. Do the same please.

Answer (score 0):

Open **targets** that described into error.

1. Open **Build Phases** tab
2. Check that you doesn't have duplicates into **Link Binaries with Libraries**

Comment: No duplicates from what I can see.